# Hook after creating a post and retrieve infos from this post immediatly

Tags: hooks

Here is an example of a function that is triggered once a post "**reservation**" has been created :

```
function new_reserv()
{

       $args = array( 'post_type' => 'reservations', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );

       $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

       while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();


               // DO some action


       endwhile;
}

add_action( 'publish_reservations', 'new_reserv');
```

So, the problem is that when creating the FIRST post "**reservation**", with the hook "**publish**" the variable "**$loop**" is empty, i.e, this hook does not allow to work on the post one just created.

Anyone knows a way to retrieve posts' infos as soon as it get created ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('save_post_reservations', 'new_reserv');
function new_reserv($post_id){
    // $post_id - just created post id
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?